# What was Nicholas Van Orton's real birthday date in "The Game"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-game

In [The Game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119174/), There are two dates mentioned as Nicholos' birthday.The first one is **October 11th**, which is mentioned while Nicholas and Conrad has a chat at the hotel.

> Conrad: and all the sudden it click... October 12th...Nickie's birthday.
>
> Nicholas: **October 11th**.
>
> Conrad: Whatever.

But, at the end of the movie the birthday invitation shows it's **October 20th**.

[image]

*Which one was Nicholas' real birthday date?*

*Does it mentioned intentionally wrong?If so,What was the purpose for that?*

Answer (score 5):

It's October 11, as Nicholas states. The celebration takes place later, on a Saturday for convenience (the 11th was a Thursday).

Comment: That's not true.Because,the function took place the same day which he falls from the building and that what his 48th birthday.The proof is,Conrad wore a same white shirt with blood stains.

Comment: Can you remiod me how we know that the day he falls is his 48th birthday? It's been a while since I saw this.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj Maybe you can elaborate on that? For me wearing the same shirt for a bunch of days is not that extraordinary when going through such an odyssey without coming home or having time to think. But maybe you mean something else (it's been a while since I watched it, I have to admit).

Comment: The invitation states the celebration takes place on the 20th, it says nothing about what on what exact day the birthday falls. Conrad gave Nicolas his gift, the CRS voucher, on his birthday. The movie's events span the 9 days between the presentation of the voucher and the fall from the building.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj There were even some party guests to say something like "nice act" referring to his jump, so it's definitely on the same evening after the jump. The point is that you can celebrate your birthday on a date _after_ your actual birthday. And it's very common to pick one of the next few Saturday evenings so everyone can make it to the party. And it's not uncommon to skip the very next Saturday due to too many guests not being able to attend. That's what http://doodle.com is good for after all

Comment: Presumably not just for convenience generally, but specifically to allow "The Game" to occur over several days.  It's been a while since I've seen the movie, but nine days seems about right for the film's events from what I remember.